How to Prevent "TypeError: fetch failed" in Next.js Page Server Component When Fetching Data from Spring Boot API?
I am working on a Next.js application where I fetch data from my Spring Boot API within a Page server component. Occasionally, my GitHub Action CI/CD pipeline fails during the Docker image build process (when executing the next build command in my Dockerfile) due to a TypeError: fetch failed error.
I understand that the error occurs because the API is not reachable from the pipeline. However, I am looking for a reliable way to prevent this error and ensure the build process completes successfully. After reading the Next.js documentation, specifically the Data Fetching Patterns section and the Rendering Server Components section (as I'm focusing on SEO for these pages), I still don't fully understand how to fetch data at runtime instead of buildtime in a Server Component. Today I will try to move the data fetching from the Page component to its own Component and wrap it with <Suspense> tag but I'm still not sure if this is the proper way to do it.
Here are some details about my setup:

Next.js version: 14.1.0 with App router

Fetching method: Using fetch within the Next.js server component.


What are the best practices or strategies to handle such errors effectively? Are there any configurations or code patterns I should follow to make my build process more robust? Additionally, how can I properly fetch data at runtime in a Server Component to avoid these issues?
Thank you for your help!

I believe that to prevent the TypeError: fetch failed error during the next build process, you might need to mock the API response during the build time. One way to achieve this could be to use a conditional check to see if the environment is the build environment and then provide a mock response. Additionally, I've read that setting up a local instance of the API in the CI/CD pipeline might help, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

@LucianaOliveira why do you assume I used AI to answer? I flagged your comment

Don't worry, MS96. My comment will be validate for the senior.
